# Method is undefined for the type, very new to java

Tags: java

I'm just starting to learn Java and for one of my assignments I need to run the variable sales from this class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader; 
import java.io.IOException;

public class Commission_main_module_improved {

    // Local variables
    //Declare Real sales, commissionRate, commission, advancedPay
    static float sales;
    static float commissionRate;
    static float commission;
    static float advancedPay;

    {
        sales = 0.12f;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        // Get the amount of sales.
        //sales = getReal("Enter the salesperson's monthly sales")

        System.out.print("Enter the salesperson's monthly sales");
        sales = Float.parseFloat(br.readLine());

        // Get the amount of advanced pay. 
        //advancedPay = getReal("Enter the amount of advanced pay, or \n 0 if no advanced pay.")

        System.out.print("Enter the amount of advanced pay, or \n 0 if no advanced pay.");
        advancedPay = Float.parseFloat(br.readLine());


        // Determine the commission rate.  
        //commissionRate h8= determineCommissionRate(sales)

        Float commissionRate = DetermineCommssionRate(sales);

        //Display the commission rate
        //Display "Commission rate: ", 100 * commissionRate, "%"

        commission = commissionRate * sales;
    }
}
```

Through this class

```
/**
 *Nethods In the this class calculate commision rate
 */
public class DetermineCommssionRate {
    public static float determineCommissionRate(float sales) {
        float cr;

        if (sales < 10000f) {
            cr = 0.10f;
        }
        else if (sales < 15000f) {
            cr = 0.12f;
        }
        else if (sales < 18000) {
            cr = 0.14f;
        }
        else {
            cr = 0.18f;
        }
        return cr;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        System.out.println(determineCommissionRate(17000f));
    }
}
```

In order to calculate the commission rate, but when I try and run the code, I get the error,

> The method DetermineCommssionRate(float) is undefined for the type Commission_main_module_improved

at the part in the first class at the line, 
`Float commissionRate = DetermineCommssionRate(sales);`

We did this in class but I haven't been able to replicate it at home. I've been trying to look up how to do this for the last 4 hours and I'm just not understanding exactly what I need to do or what I'm doing wrong, and if this is just a syntax error or if I'm trying to do something impossible. Anything to point me in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: java is case sensitive... `DetermineCommissionRate` is not the same as `determineCommissionRate`

Comment: Float commissionRate = DetermineCommssionRate.determineCommissionRate(sales);

Comment: @SashaSalauyou I wish I could downvote your comment.  If you cant help OP then at-least dont critic. Moreover OP mentioned S/he is new to java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call:

```
Float commissionRate = DetermineCommssionRate.determineCommissionRate(sales);
```

instead of

```
Float commissionRate = DetermineCommssionRate(sales);
```

since you have to call the Class.Method(argument) instead of just the Class. For future reference you should define your class with a different (noticeably) name than your class. Otherwise it should work fine.

In addition, you call

```
 System.out.println(determineCommissionRate(17000f));
```

which is a misspelling of the actual method

```
 System.out.println(determineCommssionRate(17000f));
```

You put determineCommissionRate as the method name, but it actually doesn't have an 'i' in commision.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

To access your static function use the class name to prefix your method, example below

```
DetermineCommssionRate.determineCommissionRate(1.5f));
```